# Short-circuit logic should be used in boolean contexts, is there any difference using "&", "&&"

Tags: c#, conditional-statements, bitwise-operators, logical-operators

I reviewed code and I found this operator **&** is there any difference with **&&** if I want to change to &&

```cs
public bool isTemplate(string template)
{
    return (isValid() & lc.templates.Any(x => x.Id.Equals(template, StringComparison.Current)));
}
```

Comment: For that particular code, it looks like you should indeed change to use `&&`

Comment: Operator `&&` compare boolean values (it is a test of equality to true (0) or false(1)), if first is false, next is not evaluated and result is false, and so on. Operator `&` "compare" bits (it is a binary calculation in fact), all are evaluated.

Comment: See [Boolean algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra) and [Conditional (computer programming)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_(computer_programming))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/boolean-logical-operators):

`&` operator always evaluates both operands.

`&&` operator evaluates the right-hand operand only if it's necessary.